# how to generate a table from entity using doctrine orm in own MVC application?

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, composer-php

Not able to generate a table from entity (`PatMon2.php`) using doctrine ORM in its own MVC application.

Application structure is :

```
/public
/src
..../core   with COntroller, View, Router, Request  and App.php
..../monBundle/Entity/PatMon2.php
....bootstrap.php
/vendor
compose.json

and some other folders and files.
```

I am not able to generate a table from `PatMon2.php` entity, and I am getting messages from a different project ( www\Plan2ow  instead of www\patmon2). When I created a project, I have copied it and changed namespaces. I also deleted the vendor folder and composer.lock and reinstalled doctrine with other bundles. I checked that old namespace does not exist in the new project using the search tool, which could not find word "Plan2own" in the new project. Despite this, I am not able to generate tables for the new project, and I am getting error messages containing old project namespace "Plan2own".

If I use URL: http://patmon2/index.php/home
I can see that I can include /src/bootsrap.php file and /vendor/composer/autoload_real.php. 
But if I run doctrine:orm on the command line, it complains that it can not include vendor directory.

index.php

```
<?php
print_r("C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\patmon2\public\index.php");
require '../src/bootstrap.php'; //which requires autoload.php
```

bootstrap.php

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
echo( "<br> in bootstrap INC_ROOT = ".INC_ROOT );
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
<...>
```

vendor/autoload.php

```
<?php 
<...>
        $useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION');
        if ($useStaticLoader) {
            require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload_static.php';
            print_r("<br>uses static loader");
            call_user_func(\Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit87d6e473c75d808eefba33ccc9231657::getInitializer($loader));
        }
```

output in  http://patmon2/index.php/home

```
C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\patmon2\public\index.php
in bootstrap INC_ROOT = C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\patmon2
uses static loader
```

Command line error:
`c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\patmon2>vendor\bin\doctrine  orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql`

or
c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\patmon2>php vendor\doctrine\orm\bin\doctrine

```
    uses static loader <br> in bootstrap<br> in bootstrap INC_ROOT = C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\patmon2PHP 
Warning:  require_once(../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\patmon2\src\bootstrap.php on line 69
    PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../vendor/autoload.php' 
(include_path='C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\php\PEAR;C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\frameworks\smarty\libs;C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\Plan2own\vendor;C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\patmon2\vendor') 
in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\patmon2\src\bootstrap.php on line 69
```

If i use `>php vendor\bin\doctrine` i am getting file content output:

```
dir=$(d=${0%[/\\]*}; cd "$d"; cd "../doctrine/orm/bin" && pwd)

# See if we are running in Cygwin by checking for cygpath program
if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        # Cygwin paths start with /cygdrive/ which will break windows PHP,
        # so we need to translate the dir path to windows format. However
        # we could be using cygwin PHP which does not require this, so we
        # test if the path to PHP starts with /cygdrive/ rather than /usr/bin
        if [[ $(which php) == /cygdrive/* ]]; then
                dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
        fi
fi

dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g')
"${dir}/doctrine" "$@"
```

But if i use c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\patmon2>php vendor\doctrine\orm\bin\doctrine  i am getting the error above, which complains that can not include '../vendor/autoload.php'. If i make changes to this path, website is not working. 
** ############################################################## **
This is the old versin of the question. I made changes which i did not remember in indexp.php,  bootstrap.php files. Also included ...patmon2/vendor directory to php.ini file

Command:
c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\patmon2> vendor\bin\doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql

```
Gives this output:
 <br> index.php  vendorDir  = **string(64) "C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\Plan2own\vendor"
**<br> index.php  baseDir  = **string(57) "C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\Plan2own"
**<br> index.php  vendorDir  = **string(64) "C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\Plan2own\vendor"
**<br> index.php  baseDir  = **string(57) "C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\Plan2own"
**No Metadata Classes to process.
```

I have made "Plan2own" search through all the folder, and this string was not found. I am on "www\patmon2" with the command line. **Why I am getting logs from different namespace? ANd how to tell to doctrine ORM, where are entity files, which I want to convert to tables?**

My composer.json

```
   "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "core\\" : "/src/core/",
            "src\\monBundle\\Entity\\" : "/src/monBundle/Entity/",
            "src\\monBundle\\Controller\\" : "/src/monBundle/Controller/",
            "src\\monBundle\\JsonData\\" : "/src/monBundle/JsonData/",
            "src\\monBundle\\cache\\" : "/src/monBundle/cache/",
            "src\\monBundle\\resources\\" : "/src/monBundle/resources/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "src/core/App.php",
            "src/core/View.php",
            "src/core/Controller.php"
        ]
    },    

    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "symfony/console": "~2.5",
        "twig/twig": "^1.24",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.1"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the reason was in wrong include path. When i finish the project, i will upload it to github.

in short 
`C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\patmon2\src\bootstrap.php` must contain line `require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` (not `require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';`)

On windows I should use command : `php vendor\doctrine\orm\bin\doctrine`  (not  `vendor\bin\doctrine`, or `php vendor\bin\doctrine`).